# For events A, B from a sample space X, :

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$\def\Prob{\mathop{\rm Prob}}$

> For events $A, B$ from a sample space $X$, label $A^\complement$ the event
>   complementary to $A$ (i.e., $A \cup A^\complement = X, A \cap A^\complement = \emptyset$ ), and $\Prob[A \mid B]$ denotes the probability of $A$, given that B has occurred.
>
> 1) Go with two events $A, B$ from a sample space $X$, for which
>   $\Prob[A] = 1/6$ , and $\Prob[A ∪ B] = 2/3$ . If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, calculate the following probabilities:
>
> a) $\Prob[B] =$
>
> b) $\Prob[A \cap B] =$
>
> c) $\Prob[A^\complement] =$
>
> d) $\Prob[B \mid A] =$

I am stuck on how to even do this- any hint to get started will be greatly appreciated. trying to understand it not only looking for answers.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Independence means: $\Prob(A\cap B)=\Prob (A)\cdot\Prob(B)$

Also recall: $\Prob(A\cup B)=\Prob(A)+\Prob(B)-\Prob(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0):

2/3 = Prob[A ∪ B] = Prob(A) + Prob(B and !A) = Prob(A) + Prob(B) * (1 - Prob(A)) = 1/6 + Prob(B) * (1 - 1/6)

Now finding Prob(B) is straightforward algebra.

The other probabilities just require restating them as expressions involving the probabilities of A and B.

Comment: i got Prob(B) = 1/10... did i do the math right?

Comment: @carlton.x I get 2/3 = 1/6 + Prob(B)*(1-1/6) so 1/2 = Prob(B)(5/6) so 6/10 = Prob(B).